# Howplay mp4 songs using NAudio

Tags: naudio

Can we play mp4 songs using NAudio?
Please provide some code to play mp4 songs
I need a c# code that will help me play mp4 songs

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** NAudio can now play MP4 files using the `MediaFoundationReader` assuming you have the appropriate codecs installed. This works on Windows Vista and above, and if you are running Windows Server you may need to have the "Desktop Experience" installed.

Alternative approaches would be to see if the WPF Media Element can play it, or using the Windows Media Player ActiveX control (on an OS that can play MP4s).

Answer (score 3):

You can play .mp4 files using NAudio, there is a demo in the official page.

Donwload the Demo-Apps and look for the "Media Foundation Demo". The C# code of the demo can be found at the Source Code of NAudio.

- [Link to Demo-Apps](http://naudio.codeplex.com/downloads/get/750344)
- [Link to Source Code](http://naudio.codeplex.com/downloads/get/750343)

The implementation is in the WasapiOutGuiThread class:

```
WasapiOutGuiThread  : IWavePlayer
```

Comment: Here's an example: `MediaFoundationReader reader = new MediaFoundationReader(fileName); WaveOut player = new WaveOut(); player.Init(reader);` and then just `player.Play();`