# Is it possible to view the audio waveform of mp4

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, mp4

I have been searching all over for a way to display the audio intensity of an mp4 file. I have found many guides on how to do it with wav files and even audio being actively recorded, but I can't find anything about mp4s.

I have a C# windows form that plays a video and allows you to caption it. What I am trying to do next is add a visual representation of the audio intensity so the user can see where the next chunk of speech is. To play the video I am using Windows Media Player

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this other stackoverflow question:
[Howplay mp4 songs using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609237/howplay-mp4-songs-using-naudio)
Instead of playing the file you can show the current level with some widget. Just pay attention to the fact that you should probably display the level in dB:

```
dB = 20 * log10(amplitude/maxAmplitude)
```